# Rule set optimization

Tags: reinforcement-learning, open-problems

My question is with regards to a research topic: Rule-set optimization [https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1392617/FULLTEXT02.]. If one were to use rule-set optimization for fraud detection. Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about this? I'm not able to find the right papers or references for this problem. Some have suggested Reinforcement Learning to penalize whenever a rule fails.